# Don't understand Prolog result

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm new to Prolog. I have this code:

```
loves(vincent, mia).
loves(marsellus,mia).
jealous(X,Y):- loves(X,Z), loves(Y,Z).
```

I queried `jealous(vincent,W)`. But SWI-Prolog gives me `W = vincent`!
Shouldn't it be `W = marsellus`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only the first result that you get. If you you ask Prolog interpreter to give you the next result, you will get `marsellus` as well.

The problem with your rule is that it does not prohibit `X` from being jealous of him- or herself. To fix this, add a condition that `X` must not be equal to `Y`:

```
jealous(X,Y):- loves(X,Z), loves(Y,Z), X \= Y.
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/luMb1e)